# Dev Express binding RTF data to XtraGrid

Tags: c#, devexpress, xtragrid

Is there any way I can use to bind Rich Text Format (RTF) data to the XtraGrid control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.  You should use the `RepositoryItemRichTextEdit` as the column's `ColumnEdit`. The *repositoryItem's* `DocumentFormat` should be set to **RTF**.  We also show in our demo how this can be done.  Please explore the RTF Editing module from the XtraGrid's main demo.